# How to save XML document in oracle database

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

i want to save a dynamically generated XML document in the oracle db using c#.net can anyone tell me the way to get this done

Comment: Did you try anything, e.g. google the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention your Oracle version.  (You should *always* provide the Oracle version and edition and the OS and OS version.)

This is not a simple question.  There are multiple options.

You could create a table with an XMLTYPE column.  Even with the XMLTYPE column, there are multiple options available.  XML may be stored using CLOB storage, BINARY XML storage, or into an Object Relational model.  Within the BINARY XML option, you could use BASICFILES or SECUREFILES, and have the option to enable compression.

The correct type of storage will depend on how you intend to use/search the data, but it a pretty complicated question that will require knowledge of your application system.

If you have no search/retrieval requirements beyond simple primary key lookups, then just use an XMLTYPE column with CLOB storage, and forget it.  For anything beyond that, it's a non-trivial question.

Hope that helps,

-Mark

Answer (score 1):

XML is just text. Try to insert in some CLOB or NCLOB field in your database?